# Is there a way to optimize this function?

Tags: c++, optimization, integer-arithmetic

For an application I'm working on, I need to take two integers and add them together using a particular mathematical formula. This ends up looking like this:

```
int16_t add_special(int16_t a, int16_t b) {
    float limit = std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max();//32767 as a floating point value
    float a_fl = a, b_fl = b;
    float numerator = a_fl + b_fl;
    float denominator = 1 + a_fl * b_fl / std::pow(limit, 2);
    float final_value = numerator / denominator;
    return static_cast<int16_t>(std::round(final_value));
}
```

Any readers with a passing familiarity with physics will recognize that this formula is the same as what is used to calculate the sum of near-speed-of-light velocities, and the calculation here intentionally mirrors that computation.

The code as-written gives the results I need: for low numbers, they *nearly* add together normally, but for high numbers, they converge to the maximum value of 32767, i.e.

- `add_special(10, 15) == 25`
- `add_special(100, 200) == 300`
- `add_special(1000, 3000) == 3989`
- `add_special(10000, 25000) == 28390`
- `add_special(30000, 30000) == 32640`

Which all appears to be correct.

The problem, however, is that the function as-written involves first transforming the numbers into floating point values before transforming them back into integers. This seems like a needless detour for numbers that I know, as a principle of its domain, will never not be integers.

### Is there a faster, more optimized way to perform this computation? Or is this the most optimized version of this function I can create?

I'm building for x86-64, using MSVC 14.X, although methods that also work for GCC would be beneficial. Also, I'm not interested in SSE/SIMD optimizations at this stage; I'm mostly just looking at the elementary operations being performed on the data.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Fixed. Made the mistake of transcribing the function by hand instead of copying it.

Comment: I am not following. Why are you converting those numbers to floats? If you are fine with integer arithmetic, just use 32-bit integers?

Comment: first `std::pow(limit, 2)` is a constant, second, the precision you can expect computing 16bits values might allows you to use fixed point compution

Comment: @YannDroneaud This should be [part of] an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Another alternative is to keep track of the kinetic energy (which adds linearly) instead of the velocity (which adds as per the formula).

Comment: @Eljay The formula resembles what is used to handle the addition of velocities, but the input data is very expressly *not* velocity or any measure of kinetic energy; there's no such data to reference.

Comment: Feels more appropriate for code review since your solution works and you're trying to improve it

Comment: @SergeyA I was not able to find an elegant way to perform the entire computation using only integer values of any size, hence the question. If you think there's an obvious way to perform that computation, that would be a worthy answer.

Comment: [quick-bench](http://quick-bench.com/QmGml1ghZpbp0-Mn2f6aI1McGoc) of current answers.

Comment: Is there a reason for using signed 16bit values ? Is `a` or `b` expected to be negative ?

Comment: Do you need exact results? Or is it acceptable, if the result is off by a little amount? A very crude approximation is `a+b-a*b` (in the 0..1 domain), but it can be made more precise with some additional operations and with using some lookup tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [Johannes Overmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2205033/johannes-overmann), a big performance boost is gained by avoiding `std::round`, at the cost of some (little) discrepancies in the results, though.

I tried some other little changes [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LJCreeN2RH8d0Dch), where it seems that the following is a faster approach (at least for that architecture)

```
constexpr int32_t i_max = std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max();
constexpr int64_t i_max_2 = static_cast<int64_t>(i_max) * i_max;

int16_t my_add_special(int16_t a, int16_t b)
{
    // integer multipication instead of floating point division
    double numerator = (a + b) * i_max_2; 
    double denominator = i_max_2 + a * b;
    // Approximated rounding instead of std::round
    return 0.5 + numerator / denominator;
}
```

Comment: It looks like `double numerator = (a + b) * i_max_2;` risks invoking *Undefined Behavior* as per the C++ specification on especially large values for `a` and `b`; Same for the `a * b` multiplication for the denominator. Are there any guarantees that this compiler and architecture I'm using will guarantee the integer promotion behavior that this code depends upon?

Comment: @Xirema As far as I know, `short` are implicitly converted to int before arithmetic calculations, and the multipication involve an `int64_t`, so the smaller factor is converted to `int64_t` too. The largest value reachable by `numerator` is 65534 * 32767^2 = 70362301923326, which requires 46 bits and is representable by a `double`.

Comment: Alright, good to know. I did some smoke testing with this code in an online compiler, and it does suggest you are correct in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

You might avoid floating number and does all computation in integral type:

```
constexpr int16_t add_special(int16_t a, int16_t b) {
    std::int64_t limit = std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max();
    std::int64_t a_fl = a;
    std::int64_t b_fl = b;
    return static_cast<int16_t>(((limit * limit) * (a_fl + b_fl)
                                 + ((limit * limit + a_fl * b_fl) / 2)) /* Handle round */
                                / (limit * limit + a_fl * b_fl));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae81ef6f1143d746)

but according to [Benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/ARYFP6nWeiiQyxcubhQdutZOMc0), it is not faster for those values.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Use `32767.0*32767.0` (which is a constant) instead of `std::pow(limit, 2)`.
- Use integer values as much as possible, potentially with fixed points. Just the two divisions are a problem. Use floats just form them, if necessary (depends on the input data ranges).
- Make it `inline` if the function is small and if it is appropriate.

Something like:

```
int16_t add_special(int16_t a, int16_t b) {
    float numerator = int32_t(a) + int32_t(b); // Cannot overflow.
    float denominator = 1 + (int32_t(a) * int32_t(b)) / (32767.0 * 32767.0); //  Cannot overflow either.
    return (numerator / denominator) + 0.5; // Relying on implementation defined rounding. Not good but potentially faster than std::round().
}
```

The only risk with the above is the omission of the explicit rounding, so you will get some implicit rounding.